# Elm testing: how to check if a Result is an Err?

Tags: decode, elm

I'm writing tests for functions that return a Result. How do I test that it "is" an Err (or an Ok, for that matter) ?

```
\() -> Expect.equal expectedFailure (Err _)
```

does not work.

How does one decode a non-parameter?

Comment: This won't help you now, but there is an `Expect.err` that has been added for this exact case and will be in the next release https://github.com/elm-community/elm-test/pull/90

Comment: Cool biscuits!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may well be a more elegant solution I've missed, but I personally would just write a helper function.

```
resultOk result =
    case result of
        Ok _ -> True
        Err _ -> False
```

then in your tests

```
Expect.true "expected this to be OK" (resultOk <| Ok "All good")
Expect.false "expected this to be an error" (resultOk <| Err "Oh no!")
```

`Expect.true` and `Expect.false` take a string to print if the test fails, and then an expression that should be true (in the case of `Expect.true`) or false (in the case of `Expect.false`).

Comment: I wondered if I could decode the value inside the function if it was not a parameter. I think your way is more direct and I am creating helper functions like this. Thanks